# GET request that uses more than one parameter

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi

If I build a simple FastAPI instance with a `GET` operation like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/users/{id_user}")
async def double(id_user: int):
    return {"result": id_user * 2}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

If I run the API and immediately after that I use

```
r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/8")
print(r.json())
```

I get correctly

```
{"result": 16}
```

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
@app.get("/users/{id_user}")
async def multiplication(id_user: int, k: int):
    return {"result": id_user * k}
```

How does `requests.get()` have to be written to get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are should do is something like this for two parameters

From https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/:

```
@app.get("/multiplication/")
async def multiplication(base: int = 0, times: int = 10):
    return {'response': base * times}
```

The query is the set of key-value pairs that go after the ? in a URL, separated by & characters.

For example, in the URL you will sent the params

http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/?base=0&times=10

Comment: If one of the parameters were a list (for example `l = [1, 2, 3]`) or a dictionary (for example `d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` how `requests.get()` could be written? It seems clear to me in case the parameters are numbers but with more complex data structures not.

Comment: yeah you are right by since this problem is easy my way of doing is ok by you are right for more complex problems and projects what you propose is much better